# BIND DNS strange behaviour resolving dns

Tags: bind, centos6

CentOS 6.3
BIND version 9.8.2

Server is acting as my local network's DNS server.

What happens is that I can resolve jquery.com fine, but accessing code.jquery.com results in nothing found when querying from localhost.

```
dig jquery.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.5 <<>> jquery.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38326
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 6, ADDITIONAL: 6

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jquery.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
jquery.com.             3600    IN      A       70.32.120.34

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
jquery.com.             168983  IN      NS      ns11.dnsmadeeasy.com.
jquery.com.             168983  IN      NS      ns14.dnsmadeeasy.com.
jquery.com.             168983  IN      NS      ns13.dnsmadeeasy.com.
jquery.com.             168983  IN      NS      ns15.dnsmadeeasy.com.
jquery.com.             168983  IN      NS      ns10.dnsmadeeasy.com.
jquery.com.             168983  IN      NS      ns12.dnsmadeeasy.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns10.dnsmadeeasy.com.   84449   IN      A       208.94.148.4
ns11.dnsmadeeasy.com.   84449   IN      A       208.80.124.4
ns12.dnsmadeeasy.com.   84449   IN      A       208.80.126.4
ns13.dnsmadeeasy.com.   84449   IN      A       208.80.125.4
ns14.dnsmadeeasy.com.   84449   IN      A       208.80.127.4
ns15.dnsmadeeasy.com.   84449   IN      A       208.94.149.4

;; Query time: 75 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 30 11:09:55 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 266
```

Then:

```
dig code.jquery.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.5 <<>> code.jquery.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12717
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;code.jquery.com.               IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
code.jquery.com.        43118   IN      CNAME   wac.1257.edgecastcdn.net.
wac.1257.edgecastcdn.net. 3518  IN      CNAME   ne.wac.edgecastcdn.net.
ne.wac.edgecastcdn.net. 3518    IN      A       93.184.220.20

;; Query time: 80 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 30 11:10:45 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 108
```

Then:

```
    dig jquery.com @localhost

    ; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.5 <<>> jquery.com @localhost
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10420
    ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 6, ADDITIONAL: 6

    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;jquery.com.                    IN      A

    ;; ANSWER SECTION:
    jquery.com.             3501    IN      A       70.32.120.34

    ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
    jquery.com.             168884  IN      NS      ns12.dnsmadeeasy.com.
    jquery.com.             168884  IN      NS      ns10.dnsmadeeasy.com.
    jquery.com.             168884  IN      NS      ns14.dnsmadeeasy.com.
    jquery.com.             168884  IN      NS      ns13.dnsmadeeasy.com.
    jquery.com.             168884  IN      NS      ns15.dnsmadeeasy.com.
    jquery.com.             168884  IN      NS      ns11.dnsmadeeasy.com.

    ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
    ns10.dnsmadeeasy.com.   84350   IN      A       208.94.148.4
    ns11.dnsmadeeasy.com.   84350   IN      A       208.80.124.4
    ns12.dnsmadeeasy.com.   84350   IN      A       208.80.126.4
    ns13.dnsmadeeasy.com.   84350   IN      A       208.80.125.4
    ns14.dnsmadeeasy.com.   84350   IN      A       208.80.127.4
    ns15.dnsmadeeasy.com.   84350   IN      A       208.94.149.4

    ;; Query time: 0 msec
    ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
    ;; WHEN: Tue Oct 30 11:11:34 2012
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 266
```

And this is the bit I'm stumped on:

```
    dig code.jquery.com @localhost

    ; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.5 <<>> code.jquery.com @localhost
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: It might be worth running a `tcpdump` at the same time as the query that fails.  What server(s) is bind trying to reach and why is it not able to reach them?

Comment: in the first 2 examples, it is using google's public dns to do the lookup. the second 2 using localhost. the code.jquery.com lookup locally does not resolve and I cant figure.

Comment: My bad, that error message is from `dig`, not `bind`.  Is bind still listening?  Try `sudo netstat -anp | grep named`.

Comment: yes it is listening. 127.0.0.1:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN

Comment: That looks like a TCP line.  Was there a UDP line as well?  If it is listening for UDP packets, I would try an `strace` on bind while attempting the query again next.

Comment: sorry yes there is a udp line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local bind for some reason can not reach edgecastcdn.net. While google **can** reach them. try `dig @localhost edgecastcdn.net` and `dig @ns1.edgecastcdn.net edgecastcdn.net` - you will probably get the same timeout messages.

It could be their misconfiguration issue or side effect of some DDOS attack on edgecastcdn.net or something like that.

Comment: i'm getting quite a few websites being prevented access due to (what it seems are) CDNs being blocked. This has only just started happening, which is why I am confused. If i point my desktop to google dns all is fine. so it is local to my DNS server.

Comment: What happens when you `dig @ns1.edgecastcdn.net edgecastcdn.net` ?

Comment: Is your local DNS server open to public by any chance ?

Comment: output of dig: `connection timed out; no servers could be reached.`

have an internal network, firewalled, so its not publicly accessible.

Comment: Most likely edgecastcdn.net blocks your IP (or your ISP) for some reason, maybe they had an attack from that IP. Try `ping ns1.edgecastcdn.net`

Comment: The ping is successful. The problem appears to be that for some reason my localhost dns server cannot resolve certain domains.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6287/discussion-between-sandman4-and-pixel-paul)

Comment: For some reason (and I truly have no idea why) my DNS server decided to not forward requests for the edgecast cdn, even with secondary and tertiary DNS servers added. 
What I did was to add a DNS forwarder to my router VRRP gateway (I'm using Bonded DSL) and now I can access edgecast cdns.

Thanks all for your help, very much appreciated - I think my issue was due to me drowning in DNS, a week or so break from it and figured it out.